# Multiple geometry properties in Neo4j node

Tags: neo4j, spatial-index, neo4j-spatial, neo4j-ogm

First, here is my stack description :

- Neo4j 2.3.0 on GrapheneDB + Neo4j Spatial plugin 0.15
- Ninja Framework 5.2.1 java server on my PC
- Neo4j-OGM 1.1.3 for entity mapping
- Geotools 14.0 for geostuffs
- ApacheHttp for REST queries

I have Unit nodes, which are geolocated with a property "position". The position is a Geometry (POINT, CIRCLE or POLYGON).

I create a layer and an index on this property. I can add a geolocated Unit. This is working well. It was my previous question, I resolved it because it hid the real one.

Now, I need to define some other geo objects like "path", "detectionZone" or "actionZone". And operations are typically "Which other Unit is in actionZone ?" or "Do the Unit path cross a detectionZone?"

How can I index these data ? One index for each property ? Or an index on a "wkt" property and new nodes for detectionZone, actionZone and path, with a wkt properties ?

Do I need to create a layer for each geo concept ? Or a unique "geom" layer grouping all spatial-related nodes ?

Comment: Have you already looked at [Neo4j Spatial](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial/)?

Comment: I forgot this detail : yes, the spatial plugin is enabled on the server.